# Keycloak : Rate limit on verification mail sending

Tags: keycloak

I am using keycloak for SSO.
I would like to know if there is any rate limiting option for sending verification mail. Is it possible to have a timer before a user click “resend” link for email verification while registration or after login if email is not verified ?

Becouse any One can spam with "click"  many time on the resend button and cause problems on the mail server.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find any solution to it?